# Load More pagination with angular.js | button does't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I have a question about pagination with AngularJS (ng-repeat).

The thing is that after clicking button everything works fine and other "predictions" load. But when there is nothing more to show, the button still shows up.

Maybe someone can find the bug in my code.

Link to the application: https://sportpredictions.firebaseapp.com/#/

Source code on GitHub: https://github.com/NiR-IT/tennispredictions (code specifically for pagination is in `scripts/controllers/browse.js` and `views/browse.html` files).

```
$scope.hasMoreItemsToShow = function(prediction) {
    return pagesShown < ($scope.predictions.length / pageSize);
};
```

I think the problem must be somewhere here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your template on [line 46](https://github.com/NiR-IT/tennispredictions/blob/1b2091084ee170af4f3685987c8948ab36c35efb/views/browse.html#L46):

```
<button ng-hide="hosMoreItemsToShow()" ng-click="showMoreItems()" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</button>
```

Notice `hosMoreItemsToShow` – it should be `hasMoreItemsToShow`.

Comment: @NikitaRibakovs If this resolved your issue, you should mark the answer as correct

Comment: @NikitaRibakovs Please accept this answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: But why still if to click "Load More" loads all predictions which are on website, but not only 2 as written on code?

Comment: This is completely different issue, you should create another question about it and accept my answer here.